# Authenticating POST Request When User Is Already Authenticated

Tags: java, spring, oauth

I have a site that utilizes OAuth to authenticate a user with a certificate and I make a POST request in my Java code to another service that utilizes the same system to authenticate.  What I am not sure of is how to go about authenticating a user that has already been authenticated.  Unless I blatantly ask for a user's public cert and key, (which I don't want to be doing) it will come back with an automated message asking me for a PKI.

```
URL obj = new URL(caURL);
auth_con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
auth_con.setRequestMethod("POST");

//add request header
auth_con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

auth_con.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookieString);

logger.info("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + caURL);
auth_con.setDoOutput(true);
auth_con.setDoInput(true);

File tempFile = File.createTempFile("temp", ".tmp");
input.transferTo(tempFile);
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(tempFile);

wr = new DataOutputStream(auth_con.getOutputStream());
wr.write(fis.readAllBytes());
```

Comment: Are you using only Java or some framework like Spring? Please, add the code that you use or it's difficult to help you. You're asking how to know that a user is already authenticated?

Comment: I added the code I use to make the POST request. I'm asking how to handle authentication to another service when a user is already authenticated in the current one.

Comment: The service uses Spring, but I'm using standard Java code to make the request

Comment: if OAuth2 is used, your authenticated user now has an access_token (and potentially a refresh_token). You need to send the access_token, possibly in the Authorization header as 'Bearer <access_token>`

Comment: That makes sense. We've done this between our two services, but I believe we needed to add logic to pass the token to an authorization endpoint.  I assume this similar logic would need to get added to their code.